# SpriteKit: No Collision Detection between Sprites.

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection

Setting up collision detection in SpriteKit shouldn't be a difficult endeavour, and I've done it before. Yet despite using it successfully in other projects and the abundance of documentation on the topic, I can't get it to work in my current project, and I don't know why.

The context is pretty Simple. I am adding spheres (SKSpriteNode) to a background Sprite, and then moving them with my finger expecting them to detect collisions when they touch each other. (Which does not happen).

The intended outcome is that collision is detected.

**Scene Setup:**

```
@interface GameScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
...
@implementation GameScene

// Collision BitMask
static const uint32_t planetCategory =  0x1 << 0;
```

The Scene also sets itself as the delegate for physicsWorld

```
[self.physicsWorld setContactDelegate:self];
```

I've given my scene just one Collision bitmask, because all objects are of the same type and should all hit each other. I have also set the scene to comply to the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol.

**Sprite Configuration:**

```
#pragma mark Protocol Methods (For Adding Planets)
-(void)addSKPlanetDescriptorObject:(SKPlanetDescriptor *)object
{
    if (self.allowedNodes > 0){

        SKObject *node = [[SKObject alloc]initWithImageNamed:object.imageName];
        [node setDescriptor:object];

        // Set Physics
        [node.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:planetCategory];
        [node.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:planetCategory];
        [node.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:planetCategory];

        [self.background addChild:node];
        [self.sceneObjects addObject:node];
        [node setPosition:self.pendingSpawnPoint];
        [self decreaseObjectCount];
    } else {
        [self indicateMinObjectCount];
    }
}
```

And finally, the initializer used for *SKObject*, a subclass of *SKSpriteNode*

```
@implementation SKObject


-(instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:name];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width/2]];
        [self.physicsBody setAffectedByGravity:NO];
        [self.physicsBody setUsesPreciseCollisionDetection:YES];
        [self.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];
        [self.physicsBody setMass:1000];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I've tried removing the setPhysicsBody methods outside of the init statements, I've tried changing the bitmask, I've tried omitting setCollisionBitmask and more, but I simply cannot figure out why I'm not getting any collisions.

I've also added

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    NSLog(@"Did Begin Contact");
}
```

With a line break to notify me if anything is detected. But this method never gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to all be caused by a silly mistake in the end.

To pause my game, I had a property called `BOOL isPaused`. This happens to also be a property used by SpriteKit to suspend the physics. As I fired the method `[self setIsPaused:YES];`, I inadvertently disabled collision detection. I had also failed to correctly unpause it at the time, under the belief it did not do anything. I now know it is actually a SpriteKit method.

I hope this is helpful to others if by chance they find the same problem occuring. Always make sure that your isPaused property (If used), is enabled whenever you want physics to work.

Answer (score 0):

With this simple code(just try to drag sprites), which is very similar to yours, I get everything work well (using iPhone 6 simulator)...Please try this code to see if this works for you:

```
#import "GameScene.h"
static const uint32_t planetCategory =  0x1 << 0;

@interface GameScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *ball1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *ball2;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    [self.physicsWorld setContactDelegate:self];

    SKSpriteNode *ball1 = [self createBall];

    // Set Physics
    [ball1.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:planetCategory];
    [ball1.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:planetCategory];
    [ball1.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:planetCategory];
    ball1.position = CGPointMake(100,499);
    ball1.name = @"ball1";


    [self addChild:ball1];

    SKSpriteNode *ball2 = [self createBall];



    // Set Physics
    [ball2.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:planetCategory];
    [ball2.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:planetCategory];
    [ball2.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:planetCategory];
    ball2.position = CGPointMake(100,123);
    ball2.name = @"ball2";


    [self addChild:ball2];


}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];


        if([[self nodeAtPoint:location].name isEqualToString:@"ball1"]){

            [self childNodeWithName:@"ball1"].position = location;

        }
        if([[self nodeAtPoint:location].name isEqualToString:@"ball2"]){

            [self childNodeWithName:@"ball2"].position = location;


        }
    }
}

-(SKSpriteNode*) createBall{

    SKSpriteNode *ball = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"balloon_large"];

    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];

    [ball.physicsBody setAffectedByGravity:NO];
    [ball.physicsBody setUsesPreciseCollisionDetection:YES];
    [ball.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];
    [ball.physicsBody setMass:1000];

    return ball;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    NSLog(@"Did Begin Contact");
}

@end
```

If you can't reproduce good results with this snippet then maybe you need to check other parts of your code to find what causing those issues. But let's try this first, and let me now about results...

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. I have been very busy lately and do not have as much time as I would like to work on this. I will say that while messing with the scene today, every so often all the sprites would behave correctly and collisions would be detected. This would happen if I added and moved a new sprite. After selecting another, they once again no longer detected collisions and I cannot fix that until I add a new sprite. I don't know why this happens. I will look in tonight and update here.

Comment: I found the error, I was using a BOOL property called isPaused to track whether or not my game was paused. This happens to be something used in SpriteKit as well (Which I was not aware of), therefore I was disabling physics the moment a method that paused it was fired.